# ImageMagick convert PDF to PNG: resulting image has a larger canvas than image content

Tags: pdf, png, imagemagick

When I try this

```
$ convert some_pdf.pdf[0] some_image.png
```

the resulting .png looks ok, but is contained in a much larger canvass. As a result, the original pdf slide's content appears cornered at the bottom left of the .png image.

Any clues?

Comment: Which version of ImageMagick (`convert -version`)? -- Which version of Ghostscript (`gs -v` or `gswin32c -v`)?

Comment: Can you post a link to the PDF sample file which triggers this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

My theory is that...

- (1) ...the PDF uses some weird (but 'legal') or even 'illegal' definition for its (optional) `CropBox`, `TrimBox`, `BleedBox` or/and `ArtBox` settings in relation to the (required) `MediaBox` setting,
- (2) ...and ImageMagick, not really knowing how to handle that exceptional setting, uses the MediaBox (which is the all-including box of them all) for reandering the page contents.

For example, `CropBox` (if different from `MediaBox`) tells the PDF viewer or the printer driver to render only a selected part of the complete page, and scale this part to the available space.

You can verify this easily with the help of

```
 pdfinfo  -box  -f 1  -l 100  your.pdf | grep Box:
```

A 'usual' file's outcome would be:

```
Page    1 MediaBox:     0.00     0.00   595.00   842.00
Page    1 CropBox:      0.00     0.00   595.00   842.00
Page    1 BleedBox:     0.00     0.00   595.00   842.00
Page    1 TrimBox:      0.00     0.00   595.00   842.00
Page    1 ArtBox:       0.00     0.00   595.00   842.00
Page    2 MediaBox:     0.00     0.00   595.00   842.00
Page    2 CropBox:      0.00     0.00   595.00   842.00
Page    2 BleedBox:     0.00     0.00   595.00   842.00
Page    2 TrimBox:      0.00     0.00   595.00   842.00
Page    2 ArtBox:       0.00     0.00   595.00   842.00
[...]
```

A 'weird' file's outcome could be:

```
Page    1 MediaBox:     0.00     0.00   595.00   842.00
Page    1 CropBox:      0.00    30.36   396.79   628.00
Page    1 BleedBox:     0.00    30.36   396.79   628.00
Page    1 TrimBox:      0.00    30.36   396.79   628.00
Page    1 ArtBox:      87.25    30.36   396.79   628.00
Page    2 MediaBox:     0.00     0.00   595.00   842.00
Page    2 CropBox:    148.17   210.76   445.81   630.28
Page    2 BleedBox:   148.17   210.76   445.81   630.28
Page    2 TrimBox:    148.17   210.76   445.81   630.28
Page    2 ArtBox:     148.17   210.76   445.81   630.28
[...]
```

However, to verify (or falsify) this theory I'd need access to a sample file from your original input PDFs